# Problem with .htacces RewriteRule because of name ambiguity

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I have the following index.php file in root:

```php
<?php
$error_encountered = false;
$page_to_show = "";

if (isset($_GET['page'])) {
    $page = $_GET['page'];
    if ($page == "article") {
        if (!isset($_GET['id'])) {
            $error_encountered = true;
            http_response_code(404);
            exit;
        }
        else {
            $id = $_GET['id'];
            $page_to_show = "article/article_show.php";
        }
    }
    else if ($page == "article-edit") {
        if (!isset($_GET['id'])) {
            $error_encountered = true;
            http_response_code(404);
            exit;
        }
        else {
            $id = $_GET['id'];
            $page_to_show = "article-edit/article_edit.php";
        }
    }
    else if ($page == "articles-list") {
        $page_to_show = "article-list/article_list.php";
    }
    else {
        $error_encountered = true;
        http_response_code(404);
        exit;
    }
}
else {
    $error_encountered = true;
}
if (!$error_encountered) {
    include "templates/header.php";
    include $page_to_show;
    include "templates/footer.php";
}

?>
```

I want to access article-list at the url ./articles
So I have the following .htacces file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /~number/cms/

RewriteRule ^articles$ ?page=articles-list [L]

RewriteRule ^article/([0-9]+)$ index.php?page=article&id=$1 [L]

RewriteRule ^article-edit/([0-9]+)$ index.php?page=article-edit&id=$1 [L]
```

I tried it, but when I type:
`./cms/articles`
it somehow redirects me to `./cms/articles/?page=articles`

How could this happen?

The interesting thing is that when I try the `RewriteRule ^articles ?page=articles-list [L]` without the $ and I try to access for example `./cms/articles1212` it works...

Could there be an error because of global variables, or filenames?

Comment: I just encountered something:
If I delete the whole page, the whole directory cms, it still makes the same thing:
from `./cms/articles` to `./cms/articles/?page=articles`

Comment: Do you have a physical directory `articles`? "when I type: `./cms/articles`" - You're not actually typing the `.` are you? What is the URL you are requesting? What is `/~number` in the `RewriteBase` directive? (That looks like an Apache per-user web directory.) Where is the `.htaccess` file located? You should be rewriting to `index.php` in the first rule, like the other rules. "it somehow redirects me to" - What is the HTTP status of the redirect? (Presumably you do mean an external redirect?).

Comment: You are looking at client side cached results. Use a fresh anonymous browser instance every time you test. And always make an explicit deep reload (CTRL-R typically, but that depends on the browser you use). And check the network tab in your browser's console to learn whether the response has been loaded from the server or from the local, client side cache.